# Make APFS external Hard Drive without EFI

Tags: disk-utility, partition

Is there any option to do a reset of an external hard drive without losing space on the hard drive? I want to use APFS Format and the only way to do it is with Terminal:

1. Locate hard drive with : `diskutil list`
2. Reset hard drive with: `diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ Emptied /dev/diskX` (it is creating a EFI Volume)

Actually I´m losing Space with this method. If I do it with the same code and replace it with "APFS". I got this error message: *"A GUID Partition Table (GPT) partitioning scheme is required."*

[image]

Comment: 1) You should always format Mac disks on GUID, not MBR. 2) Why does it really matter for the sake of a few MB? You shouldn't ever fill any disk sufficiently for this to become an issue. 3) HDs are still best on HFS+, not APFS.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! - A lot of people say that APFS is the better choice for SSD´s. But I´m not sure... I know I shouldn't fill up the hard drive so much. However, I don't understand why I can't delete the partition....

Comment: APFS for SSH, HFS+ for HD. Disk Utility won't even show you the EFI partition & if you remove it using Terminal, it won't easily let you move the start of the next partition up to fill the gap. You'd either need something like [Paragon Hard Disk Manager](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hdm-mac/) or just forget about it ;)